# Impersonation exception using SQLFileStream in c#

Tags: c#, impersonation

Our application is using Filestream columns to hold images in the database. The application runs perfectly on the desktops using windows 7 but gives a exception on the Windows XP machines. The following exception is thrown:

**"Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid."**

I have tested several accounts on both the Windows XP en Windows 7 workstations but all refuse to work on the XP machines. 
The database is SQLServer 2008R2 running on a Server 2008R2. All clients and the server are part of the same domain.

Comment: Did you check these posts: 1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/50ea9248-6edd-4f6a-bbc3-b1d119849341 2. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2255379 ?

Comment: I have read both of them. The msdn post marks the SQL2008 to server 200R2 as the answer but does not apply to my application. Later in that post someone suggests editing the local policies for impersonation. I have tried those modifications, but it didn’t help.

Comment: The error from Microsoft support comes close to my problem but concerns asp.net and not a windows application. I tried their solutions by running the application on a windows XP machine with .NET framework 4 installed. It still won’t run.
I got a reply on the Microsoft forums about running my code in a impersonation block. I’m looking in to this now and will post if I find something.